# Map Navigator for SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5, navigator

i'd like to ask about your idea how we can implement a map navigator in SAPUI5? For example, we need to get the current location of the user, then suggest the nearest fastfood around him. Is this possible in SAPUI5?

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible.. Search in the internet and come up with something.

Get started here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/map-geolocation/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to integrate map API into a SAPUI5 application. Firstly you need to decide which map provider should be used in your case. for example, if you want to use google map you can refer to this blog https://blogs.sap.com/2014/07/01/google-maps-library-for-ui5/

But SAPUI5 library provides a map control to integrate with geo map. you can refer to http://veui5infra.dhcp.wdf.sap.corp:8080/sapui5-sdk-dist/test-resources/sap/ui/vbm/bestpractices.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use either SAP controls for that, for example this one:
sap.ui.vbm.GeoMap

Or you could pick any free JS third-party library and integrate it with your sapui5 view.
(There are many threads explaining how to use third-party libraries in sapui5).